# probabilities distribution-find the right answer

Tags: probability

I have a company that produces 1000 pounds of plastic. It follows the normal distribution with mean 297.9 and standard deviation is 3.5. One method  has been used 22 times and the average is 299.9. It must be pass the 0.05 significance test. Choose the right answer:

a) we can't decline the $H_0$ with $z=2.6802$

b) we decline the $H_0$ with $z=2.6802$

c) we decline the $H_0$ with $z= 1.3401$

d) we can't decline the $H_0$ with $z= 1.3401$

e) something else

I wasn't able to find those results it asks, and I DON'T think it is something else.

**What I have tried:**

$s=s^2 /\sqrt n =22/ \sqrt{3.5}$ and I find $s$ then I make a replacement in the normal distribution below, but I can't write it in the proper form.

$m=299.9$, $x=297.9$, and

```
x-tn-1:1-a/2 Sx <= m <= x+tn-1:1-a/2 Sx  = 1-a
```

Comment: $3.5/\sqrt{22}$ is not $22/\sqrt{3.5}$

Comment: @Gribouillis I just wanted to show that I have done those ..anyway https://atozmath.com/CONM/DistributionTables.aspx?q=z&q1=z%602%600.05%602.6802&do=1 can a calculator answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

The $22$ independent samples individually follow the law ${\mathcal N}(297.9, 3.5^2)$, hence their average $X$ follows ${\mathcal N}(297.9, \frac{3.5^2}{22})$, hence $Z = \frac{X-297.9}{3.5/\sqrt{22}}$ follows ${\mathcal N}(0,1)$. In our case
\begin{equation}
z=\frac{299.9-297.9}{3.5/\sqrt{22}}=2.6802
\end{equation}
For the normal law, the $0.05$ significance test declines $H_0$ if $|z|>1.96$. It is the case here, so the correct answer is b)

Here is how to compute the value of $z$ in Python

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> (299.9 - 297.9)/(3.5/sqrt(22))
2.68023757704196
```

Comment: https://www.calculator.net/z-score-calculator.html?c1raw=299.0&c1mean=297.9&c1sd=3.5&calctype=zscore&x=35&y=4

Comment: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Hypothesis-testing-calculator.php#answer

Comment: I can't find the answer you wrote on calculators...you can see I wanted to test your answer and I don't find z like you wrote it

Comment: I wanted to test if your result indeed is right

Comment: Sorry but I already did the (home?)work for you. I think you can check the answer yourself. Perhaps you need to learn how to use these calculators?

Comment: its not homework its for me .I just want to learn probabilities :) I am very greatful that you help me,but I wanted to check that result .I want to be sure that it is like that way

Comment: I check the $$ z=299.0−297.93.5/22−−√=2.6802 $$  but if you calculate it is not equal with 2.6802 it is with 1.46666666

Comment: Sorry I wrote $299.0$ instead of $299.9$